# Find all the supervisors of an employee

Tags: postgresql, recursive-query

I know the answer would seem to be to use "WITH RECURSIVE" as per [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10191746/recursive-select) but I'm just not getting it.

I have a table called `people`, and a table called `position_hierarchy`.  The `people` table has a unique id `uperson_id` and position id we call `pcn` and an `enabled` flag (because when somebody leaves and is replaced, their replacement gets the same `pcn`).  The `position_hierarchy` has the column `pcn`, and another column `reports_to` which is the `pcn` of the person above them in the hierarchy.  What I want to do is give a person's `uperson_id` and find all the `uperson_id`s of the people above them in the hierarchy, and/or give a `uperson_id` and another person's `uperson_id` and tell if the second person somebody who has a supervisory position over the first.

The president of the company is indicated because their `pcn` is the same as their `reports_to`.  (Not my decision - I would have used a null `reports_to`)

What I came up with so far is:

```
with recursive parents (uperson_id, pcn, reports_to) as
(
 select p1.uperson_id, ph1.pcn, ph1.reports_to
 from people p1
 join position_hierarchy ph1 on ph1.pcn = p1.pcn
 where reports_to != ph1.pcn and active_revoke_flag = '0'

 union all

 select p2.uperson_id, ph2.pcn, ph2.reports_to
 from people p2
 join position_hierarchy ph2 on p2.pcn = ph2.pcn
 join parents pp on pp.pcn = ph2.reports_to
)
select parents.* from parents where uperson_id = 'aaa3644';
```

but that returns 5 rows with the same uperson_id, pcn and reports_to (which seems like the right number of rows, but I want the supervisor's uperson_id at each level.  I feel like I'm missing something very basic, and I'll probably slap my head when you tell me what I'm doing wrong.

**What I did**

Based on [Erwin Brandstetter's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12231470/3333), I fixed a few things (mostly because I didn't make clear which table the `active_revoke_flag` was in) and came up with:

```
with recursive p as (
    select pcn, reports_to
    from   position_hierarchy
    where  pcn = (SELECT pcn FROM people WHERE uperson_id = 'aaa3644')
    union all
    select ph2.pcn, ph2.reports_to
    from   p
    join   position_hierarchy ph2 ON ph2.pcn = p.reports_to AND
           p.pcn != p.reports_to
)
select p2.uperson_id, p2.active_revoke_flag, p.*
from   p
join   people p2 USING (pcn)
where  p2.active_revoke_flag = '0';
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would try this bottom up approach, start with the person of interest and work my way up:

```
with recursive p as (
    select p1.uperson_id, p1.pcn, ph1.reports_to
    from   people p1
    join   position_hierarchy ph1 USING (pcn)
    where  ph1.active_revoke_flag = '0'
    and    p1.uperson_id = 'aaa3644'

    union all

    select p2.uperson_id, p2.pcn, ph2.reports_to
    from   p
    join   position_hierarchy ph2 ON ph2.pcn = p.reports_to
                                 AND ph2.active_revoke_flag = '0'
    join   people p2 ON p2.pcn = ph2.pcn
)
select * from p;
```

Or, faster, because we only join to `person` once:

```
with recursive p as (
    select pcn, reports_to
    from   position_hierarchy
    where  active_revoke_flag = '0'
    and    pcn = (SELECT pcn FROM person WHERE uperson_id = 'aaa3644')

    union all

    select ph2.pcn, ph2.reports_to
    from   p
    join   position_hierarchy ph2 ON ph2.pcn = p.reports_to
                                 AND ph2.active_revoke_flag = '0'
)
select p2.uperson_id, p.*
from   p
join   people p2 USING (pcn); -- assuming pcn is unique in table person
```

As an aside: I do find your design with duplicate `pcn` somewhat dubious.

Comment: I like the second one.  It can be faster indeed, and in some cases this approach will improve readability a lot by excluding columns not relevant in the iteration.

Comment: Second one is giving me an infinite loop.

Comment: Ok, I added the check for ph2.pcn != ph2.reports_to, and now it terminates.

Answer (score -2):

If you know the maximum tree depth, you can kludge it into a single query; otherwise, you need to read Joe Chelko and restructure your tables.

A single query for a maximum depth of 5 might look like this (untested):

```
select distinct ph1.pcn
from position_hierarchy ph1
join position_hierarchy ph2 on ph1.pcn = ph2.reports_to
left join position_hierarchy ph3 on ph2.pcn = ph3.reports_to
left join position_hierarchy ph4 on p3.pcn = ph4.reports_to
left join position_hierarchy ph5 on ph4.pcn = ph5.reports_to
where ph2.pcn = @my_pcn
or ph3.pcn = @my_pcn
or ph4.pcn = @my_pcn
or ph5.pcn = @my_pcn;
```

The result will be a list of the pcn's of all of @my_pcn's superiors.  You could also add something to test for the edge case of the company president.

Chelko wrote the book on hierarchies in SQL, literally: http://books.google.ca/books/about/Joe_Celko_s_Trees_and_Hierarchies_in_SQL.html?id=Jy4e8SbYO6sC

Comment: A recursive query is a perfect fit for this kind of problem. No need to do that mulit-join thing

Comment: I'm not planning to restructure the tables or assume a maximum depth, but thanks for the link to the book.

Comment: I downvoted because you are factually wrong on the need to restructure tables.  It is worth noting that different database systems have different approaches to this problem and your approach is probably only needed in a lowest-common-denominator db like MySQL.

Comment: Celko's Trees and Hierarchies is a workaround for databases that don't support recursion. If you have recursion available, don't use a bad schema design. It's slow, not reliable and hard to maintain.

Comment: @FrankHeikens: I disagree about the slowness and the "bad schema design". What's wrong with "Closure" for example compared with hierarchies and recursive queries?

Comment: @ypercube: Referential integrity is one of the problems, inserting and updating is another one: You have to update many records for inserting or updating a single record.

Comment: Yes, I agree, abit more complex inserts and updates. But the queries will be simpler (and in occasions that means faster). And cascading deletes (if you need them) are easier to deal with.

Comment: Chris Travers (and others) - has PostgreSQL actually changed the basic math of relational data somehow, or does a recursive query just execute the same statement multiple times on the server side, the same way a custom-written stored procedure would? Normally, there are two problems with using recursive queries in any RDBMS (with or without syntactic sugar): (1) they can execute the same statement multiple times, and (2) their performance isn't predictable. I'm guessing that Paul's app isn't high-demand enough for either of those to matter, though.

Comment: PostgreSQL chest-thumping aside, the other problem that Chelko's book solved is selecting a subtree: for example, instead of querying who a person reports to (a simple list of ancestors), what if Paul had to query everyone who reports to a person, directly or indirectly?  There could be thousands of results in a big company, and you wouldn't want PostgreSQL to execute the query statement thousands of times internally.